# Not able no read telegram channel messages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am trying to read messages posted on Telegram group called "Into the Cryptoverse"

Here is the code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = "MY_API_ID"
api_hash = "MY_API_HASH"
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='Into The Cryptoverse'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

And when I run the program and somebody posts a message in that group, I get this error:

```
> Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-57' coro=<UpdateMethods._dispatch_update() done, defined at C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py:471> exception=ValueError('Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Into The Cryptoverse"')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 511, in _dispatch_update
    await builder.resolve(self)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 99, in resolve
    await self._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\newmessage.py", line 93, in _resolve
    await super()._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 103, in _resolve
    self.chats = await _into_id_set(client, self.chats)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 33, in _into_id_set
    chat = await client.get_input_entity(chat)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 437, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 574, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Into The Cryptoverse"
Process finished with exit code 0
```

And when I try to type name the chat group like this: "Into_The_Cryptoverse", I get this error again whenever someone posts a message in the group:

```
> Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-37' coro=<UpdateMethods._dispatch_update() done, defined at C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py:471> exception=UsernameInvalidError('Nobody is using this username, or the username is unacceptable. If the latter, it must match r"[a-zA-Z][\\w\\d]{3,30}[a-zA-Z\\d]" (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 511, in _dispatch_update
    await builder.resolve(self)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 99, in resolve
    await self._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\newmessage.py", line 93, in _resolve
    await super()._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 103, in _resolve
    self.chats = await _into_id_set(client, self.chats)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 33, in _into_id_set
    chat = await client.get_input_entity(chat)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 437, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 553, in _get_entity_from_string
    result = await self(
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\balatka.da\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 84, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UsernameInvalidError: Nobody is using this username, or the username is unacceptable. If the latter, it must match r"[a-zA-Z][\w\d]{3,30}[a-zA-Z\d]" (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)
```

Can you please help me find a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

don't use chat title as an entity. it's not reliable.
use usernames only, chats="intocryptoverse"

---

alternatively if no username for said chat (private group you have joined), you need to naturally do either of:

- find the id (integer) of the chat with a forked Telegram client, pass it to chats=.
- make a string match to the channel.title for all events, more overhead and less reliable than username or id, and probably wasted requests if telegram didn't send full chat info, ex:

```
@client.on(...)
async def only_that_chat(event):
    if not event.is_group or \ 
       (await event.get_chat()).title != "my chat title": return 

    # code here

    # no users or broadcast channels, only small and big groups, also return if the channel name doesn't match.
```

- additionally, you can also just trigger a [global search](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/search.html) for all public chats (search icon in clients) to find id/username of a chat matching your title, and use that.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get it. Could please post a functional whole code here. Thank you.